# Meta class inside class, how to get the name of the top class

Tags: python, django

The question comes from django. It's a thing that it does by default but I don't understand how.

I have a Meta Class that needs a lower case of the name of the original class. How can I get that?

```
class Student(models.Model):

    class Meta:
        db_table =  #by default this becomes "student"
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a decorator for this. During the class initialization `Student` doesn't exist, so you can set that only after class definition.

```
def lower_db_name(cls):
    cls._meta.db_table = cls.__name__.lower()
    return cls

@lower_db_name
class Student(models.Model):
    class Meta:
        pass
```

Comment: I get "type object has no attribute Meta"

Answer (score 1):

Django does it with a metaclass. You could do something similar:

```
class ModelMeta(type):
    def __new__(cls, cls_name, bases, attrs):
        if 'Meta' in attrs and not hasattr(attrs['Meta'], 'db_table'):
            attrs['Meta'].db_table = cls_name.lower()

        return super(ModelMeta, cls).__new__(cls, cls_name, bases, attrs)

class Model:
    __metaclass__ = ModelMeta

class Student(Model):
    class Meta:
        thing = 12
```

Comment: The problem is that I still need to inherit Django's models.Model because of other properties. and when I add your solution with that I get this error: "metaclass conflict: the metaclass of a derived class must be a (non-strict) subclass of the metaclasses of all its bases"

Comment: @Kiarash: Well that's a completely different problem. You will have to subclass Django's `models.Model`'s metaclass, override `__new__` to do this, and create a new `Model` whose metaclass is your new metaclass.